# CSS: Overflow Auto and Z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/smnde/2/

Is there a way to make the list show up above the div when `overflow:auto` is set? Like in the second container?

Comment: Don't use overflow:auto?

Comment: I'm using this inside a modal window, so I need the vertical scroll.

Comment: Ah, just seen the answers and understand the question better now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes; you can display `overflow` `div` outside of anything `div` when the `child` is `absolute position` & it's `parent` didn't have `position:relative`

like this:

```
#button {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 5px;
}

#hidden {
     display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-20px;
    left:190px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/smnde/26/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this will break if any parent object is positioned. Since the container is part of a modular window its not possible to use this.

Comment: about position i already define it . This trick is not use first time. We can use them without any problem. You can sreach in google

Comment: What I mean is that you can't use **any** position directive on **any** parent of the box...
Check: http://jsfiddle.net/smnde/27/

Comment: You both get ups but I gotta give it to sandeep. I used .position() instead of .offset() in order to position my list (each row has a similar list on mouseOver). Thank you both!

Comment: @sandeep Is there a way to make the child appear at the same level of the parent. Your solution is great, but the child can only be at a fixed position.

Answer (score 2):

No, overflow will not display anything outside the box.

You can use a tooltip like hover instead with the hidden box outside the container.

Check:
http://jsfiddle.net/smnde/9/