# How can I get an absolute element to float right within its parent?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to get a dropdown to work as part of a menu.  I have a ul with a few li elements added on the left and then I want to have an li element float to the right.  I was doing this using relative position before, but now I want it to be able to overflow and display over anything below it.

I found this question:
[CSS: Overflow Auto and Z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790981/css-overflow-auto-and-z-index)
and found out you have to use absolute position to get this sort of overflow to happen.  So, how would I do this?

This is the basic code structure:

```
<ul>
    <li id="right_item1"/> (relatively positioned)
    ...
    <li id="absolute_position"/> (absolutely positioned, floating right)
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean with overflow? As in `overflow` CSS like (scrolling the screen) or making it "hover" over content below it?

Comment: Hover over the content below it.  I was using the overflow property in css to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
ul{
    position:relative; // You need this
}

#absolute_position{
   position:absolute;
   right:0;
   bottom:0; 

}
```

Comment: I have to add that in my situation, when I set the 'ul' to be scrollable, the dropdown will be cut by the ul. @QoP's answer only works if you have a unscrollable 'ul' .